# Multiple characters in a string return a false boolean when trying to find a character in the string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, character

```
#Function takes a character and a string and returns a boolean reflecting if
#the character is found in the string.
def isItThereS(letter, word):
    letInWord = 0
    for l in word:
        if l == letter:
            letInWord += 1
    return letInWord == True
```

When I put it in the operator like

> > > isItThereS("h","hello world")
> > >       True

but when I go to find a character that repeats like "l" or "o" it returns false.

> > > isItThereS("l","hello world")
> > >       False

How would I go about getting that to not return false, but instead return True since the character is technically in the string?

Comment: because `True` evaluates as `1` so if the occurrence is >1 then you would get wrong output. You must use in-built methods like `str.find()` to perform such operations, or if you still want to modify this piece of code then use `return not letInWord  == False`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply use the in operator

```
def isItThereS(letter, word):
  return letter in word
```

Comment: btw the function name is can be improved

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** want to use a custom function for that, change your return to `return letInWord >= 1`. As everything but `1 == True` will evaluate to `False`. (So a more appropriate name for the function as is would be `is_it_there_only_once`).

Otherwise please use the solution provided by armak.